# POST empty fields result in query error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms, mysqli

I have a form with some fields

```
<form action="add.php" method="post">
/*Some fields*/
</form>
```

Also I created the following function to quote and escape form submitted values

```
<?php
    // Quote and escape form submitted values
    function db_quote($value) {
        $connection = db_connect();//Connection with database "NO ISSUE HERE"
        return "'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$value) . "'";//Maybe the issue here
     }
?>
```

Then I pass values to the function as following

```
$inventoryId = db_quote($_POST['inventoryId']);
$sn = db_quote($_POST['sn']);
$model = db_quote($_POST['model']);
//etc...
```

Every thing work fine if I fill all the fields, but if there is at least one empty filed i.e. no value entered by the user I get the following error

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string in etc...
```

Here is the query I am trying to run

```
<?php
    $sql = "INSERT INTO inventory (id,manufacturer_id,supplier_id,servicer_id,operator_id,sn,model,inventory_name,inventory_type,description,power,purchase_order,purchase_cost,arrival_date,installation_date,warranty_date,incident_history,conditions,m_next_date,m_start_date,m_deadline,lifetime,inspection_frequency,location,purchased_from)
    VALUES ($inventoryId,$manufacturer,$supplier,$servicesId,$operatorId,$sn,$model,$inventoryName,$inventorType,$description,$power,$purchaseOrder,$purchaseCost,$arrivalDate,$installationDate,$warranty,$incident,$conditions,$nextDate,$startDate,$deadline,$lifetime,$inspection,$location,$purchasedFrom);";

    if ($connection->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "<p>New inventory ".$inventoryId." created successfully</p>";
    } else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $connection;
    }
    $connection->close();
?>
```

Update: The issue only with Auto Increment columns

Comment: I think you missed out `''` on `$inventoryId,$manufacturer,` like `'$inventoryId','$manufacturer',`

Comment: @RubahMalam db_quote add the single quotation mark ''

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    // Quote and escape form submitted values
    function db_quote($value) {
        $connection = db_connect();//Connection with database "NO ISSUE HERE"
        return "'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$value) . "'";//Maybe the issue here
     }
?>
```

Convert it to

```
<?php
    // Quote and escape form submitted values
    function db_quote($value) {
        if(!$value) return '';
        $connection = db_connect();//Connection with database "NO ISSUE HERE"
        return "'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$value) . "'";//Maybe the issue here
     }
?>
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work. Still getting the same error if least one empty filed. Thank you.

Comment: try once using sprintf php function while creating your sql